# How can I get all my checkins in Visual Studio 2010 TFS?

Tags: tfs

On Many occasions, I need to review my checkins. 
Is there a way I can get all my checkins in TFS? I don't mean view history on a particular file, but all my checkins! If I can filter based on start and end date would be great

I am new to TFS!!!

Any suggestions

Comment: But your history, which you say your not looking for, will in deed show you all of your checked in files, as well as other users check ins.

Comment: Let suppose I need to review  all the files that a developer has checked in how do I do that? Or if I need to fix a bug and I know i need to apply the same fix as i did some time ago but dont remember where I have applied the fix How do I go about it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can probably get what you need from the command line TF.EXE program. The command to do this should be something like this (run it from a Visual Studio command prompt):

`TF.EXE history /server:http://tfs:8080 "$/" /recursive /user:username /noprompt /format:detailed`

You can manipulate the "$/" to go to a more nested folder if you need to reduce your output.

You'll also want to redirect this to a file (using `> output.txt` or something) as there's a lot of information here.

`TF.EXE history /?` will give you a list of options.

Comment: Note, if the current folder is mapped to a server you don't need to specify '/server:...'.

Answer (score 14):

1. Open "Team Explorer" (Found in "View"-menu)
2. Find the team-project and expand "Team Members"
3. Right-click the team member and select "Show Checkin History".

But it is very strange that one cannot do this filtering directly, when viewing the entire history of a team-project.

Yet another alternative is to use the "Link to"-search within TFS WorkItem:

1. Open a TFS Workitem
2. Choose the "All Links"-tab
3. Press the "Link To"-button
4. In the new dialog set "Link Type" to "Changeset" and press "Browse..."-button.
5. Now you have a TFS search dialog, where one can specify username and other filtering

See also [VS2010 - Find Information About a Changeset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245461.aspx)

Comment: I believe this option is only available with the TFS Power Tools installed.

Answer (score 6):

Go to TFSServer Explore --> Branch (Folder) --> Right Click --> Find ---> Find Changesets--> "By user" 
--Enter User ID.

This will bring all the checkins for a user for a branch.

Answer (score 3):

Under View you can see "Pending Checkins".

View -> Other Windows - > Pending Changes.

Also, if you wanted you can download "team Foundation Sidekicks"

http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

http://www.attrice.info/downloads/index.htm

Which is a free tool and from it you can do queries on your workspaces, check-in status, changes, etc.

Comment: Let suppose I need to review  all the files that a developer has checked in how do I do that? Or if I need to fix a bug and I know i need to apply the same fix as i did some time ago but dont remember where I have applied the fix How do I go about it?

Comment: That's where the Team Foundation Sidekicks program comes in. You can search for a person, and it will show you everything they have checked out, and then you can search by what they have checked in. You can also do this in TFS by looking the history. There are lot of 3rd party tools for this (TFS Power tools too). For fixes, what do you use for issue tracking ( bug tracking)? Wouldn't it be in there?

Answer (score 3):

In VS 2015:

1. On "Source Control Explorer" go to the folder you want (can be the top folder in order to get all possible check-ins).
2. Right click and on the context menu select "Find" -> "Find changesets..."
3. On "By User:" fill in the desired user name (yours).
4. Choose whatever other filtering you want (Changeset number range, Created date range)
5. Click "Find"